# Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Ajax compatible version with jQuery

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm creating a new ASP.NET MVC 4 project and I'm trying to update jQuery using NuGet. I receive the following error:

> Updating 'jQuery' from version '1.8.2' to '2.0.0' in project 'X.Web'.
>   Update-Package : Updating 'jQuery 1.8.2' to 'jQuery 2.0.0' failed.
>   Unable to find a version of 'Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Ajax'  that
>   is compatible with 'jQuery 2.0.0'. At line:1 char:1
>   + Update-Package jQuery
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Update-Package], Exception
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.UpdatePackageCommand

Looking at the support page for [Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Ajax](http://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Ajax/) on NuGet it appears it doesn't support jQuery 2.0. Is there a workaround or is my only option to remove the Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Ajax script from the project?

**Update**
Since jQuery 2.0. doesn't support IE8, I installed version 1.9.1 instead. This was the latest version (as of 5/15/2013) that supported IE6 and higher. I'm sure there is a way through the NuGet Package Manager GUI to do this, but I went to the console to install using the following command:
Update-Package jQuery -Version 1.9.1

To avoid others having this issue, they should update the NuGet to show the two options for jQuery, the latest 1.9.x library and the latest 2.0.x library.

Comment: jQuery 1.9 and 2.0 are identical in functionality, except 2.0 drops support for older browsers, and by older I mean anything less than IE9 and some ancient versions of Firefox and Opera.  IE8 and lower is not supported, which is probably not what you want.

Comment: Good point. I'll go with 1.9.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the moment there's no workaround and the only thing you can do is downgrade back to jQuery 1.9

Just a side-note: Be careful when updating to jQuery 2.0 as it breaks compatibility with older browsers, but I guess you probably already knew that.